# What is the [0/0] that pops up in corner of tmux vim if I try to scroll up?

Tags: macvim, scrolling, tmux

When I'm in vim on tmux with terminal and I scroll up, the cursor will jump to where my mouse is and show a `[0/0]` on the right corner of my window. When that happens, I can't type or move the cursor at all with my hjkl keys. The only way to get it back is to scroll down and the cursor will go back to where it was and the `[0/0]` will go away. Why does this happen and what exactly is it doing?

[image]

This is what it looks like.

Comment: A similar indicator appears in tmux when activating copy-mode (which happens with certain key triggers, but also when tmux captures a scroll). Try this in a shell with lots of output.

Comment: So what exactly does it mean? Because when in scroll mode it will show the number of lines that are in the window but in this case i'm not in scroll mode at all.